# How do I find currently loaded mode (syntax) in Ace Editor?

Tags: ace-editor

Well as the title says - how do I find out what the currently loaded mode is in Ace Editor?

editor.getSession().getMode() does not really return anything I can use - have looked through the objects returned somewhat - but could not find anything.

editor.getTheme() returns a string to me that I can use however - just seems funny if they did not do somewhat the same for mode

Answer (score 8):

To retrieve the name of the mode you use:

```
editor.getSession().getMode().$id
```

Answer (score 4):

I tried Hugeen's answer and experienced the `undefined` error just like lorefnon reported. This is what worked for me:

```
// get the editor instance
var editor = ace.edit('editorid');

// get the current mode
var mode = editor.session.$modeId;

// modeid returns the full string (ace/mode/html), cut to the mode name only
mode = mode.substr(mode.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Hope that helps someone!

Comment: If I try `.getMode().$id` in browser, everything is fine, but it doesn't if I do the same in my code. `$modeId` works great however! Any idea what the reason could be? Does `getMode()` possibly return the initial mode settings instead of the current?

Answer (score 0):

The clean way to get this without any somersaults:

```
var mode = editor.session.mode;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ace `v1.32.7`:

```js
mode = editor.getOption('mode')
console.log(mode)
```

prints

```
ace/mode/javascript
```