# Ace code editor: Render entire code to HTML?

Tags: ace-editor, html-rendering

Ace is smart when it comes to rendering code with highlighting and doesn't render all the code, but only a bit more than the current view requires.

However, for my use case I need to get the rendered HTML source of the entire code. Is there a way to make it render all my code at once?

Comment: Do you need it to be rendered inside the editor and be editable, or just need  the html for something (e.g. printing)?

Comment: Just the HTML code as string, non-editable, to use it outside of the editor. In fact, I want to inject the code into a otherwise blank page, so that I can copy and paste the code including syntax highlighting into a Google Docs document. Copy/paste inside the editor does not carry over the syntax highlighting, whereas copying the rendered HTML preserves it (I guess the clipboard content is in RTF format).

Comment: do you mean `document.getElementsByClassName('ace_content')[0].innerHTML` doesn't return the whole code?

Comment: @MaherFattouh is does not. It returns the static HTML for the code that is currently visible in the editor. If there's a lot of code, only a small part of the rendered HTML is given. This is an optimization of ACE, but what I want is static rendering of the whole code I pass to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"a user" pointed me in the right direction. I hacked together something that works for me using an ace build: https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/

[image: Preview of solution]

Regular ACE editor on the left, statically highlighted HTML on the right.
 Initially, the page source is used as content, but can be changed in the editor and the right panel is re-rendered instantly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>ACE Static Highlighter</title>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            body {
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            #editor, #static { 
                margin: 0;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: 50%;
            }

            #static {
                left: 50%;
                right: 0;
                overflow: auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre id="editor"></pre>
        <pre id="static"></pre>
        <script src="ace/build/src/ace.js"></script>
        <script src="ace/build/src/ext-static_highlight.js"></script>
        <script>
            var highlight = ace.require("ace/ext/static_highlight")
            var dom = ace.require("ace/lib/dom")

            var codeEl = document.getElementById("static");
            var editor = ace.edit("editor");
            //editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/html");
            //editor.setTheme("ace/theme/twilight");
            editor.setOptions({
                showPrintMargin: false,
                mode: "ace/mode/html",
                theme: "ace/theme/twilight"
            });
            editor.session.setValue(document.documentElement.outerHTML);
            doHighlight(editor, codeEl);

            editor.session.on("change", function() {
                doHighlight(editor, codeEl);
            });

            function doHighlight(editor, codeEl) {
                codeEl.textContent = editor.session.getValue();
                highlight(codeEl, {
                    // broken, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/31882064/2044940
                    //mode: editor.session.getMode().$id,
                    mode: editor.session.$modeId,
                    theme: editor.getTheme(),
                    startLineNumber: 1,
                    showPrintMargin: false,
                    trim: true
                }, function (highlighted) {
                    var themeStyleId = editor.getTheme().replace("/theme/", "-");
                    var match = document.getElementById(themeStyleId).innerHTML.match(
                        new RegExp(`.${themeStyleId}\\s+\\{[^}]*?background-color:\\s*?([^;,}]+)`)
                    );
                    if (match) {
                        codeEl.style.backgroundColor = match[1];
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If there's a less hackish way to get the theme's background color, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

you can use ace/ext/static_highlight  similar to https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/1480#issuecomment-20201314 and https://github.com/shadowcodex/c9.ide.print/blob/master/c9.ide.print.js